# How safely generate HTML pages on GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

I'm developing `GWT` application which has many different forms. Visibility of these forms depends on type of authorized user. In other words, I want to do the following:

```
String type = rpc.getUserType(); // ask from server only ONCE

if(type.equals("advancedUser"))
{
   ContentPanel advPanel= new ContentPanel();
   add(advPanel);
}

if(type.equals("admin"))
{
   ContentPanel adminPanel= new ContentPanel();
   add(adminPanel);
}
```

My question is the following:
Is getting user type from server only once and using this variable everywhere safe? I mean is there any possibility to change this variable (if it stored on client side)?

My friend told me that GWT prepares html on server side, so I can safely store type in one variable and use it - nobody can acces it.

But i think, that i **have to make rpc call before each** construction like `if(userType=blah-blah-blah) add(something)` because I think that GWT translates my Java code to Javascript which runs on client side and all variables can be modified with programms like ArtMoney.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is the following: Is getting user type from server only once and using this variable everywhere safe? I mean is there any possibility to change this variable (if it stored on client side)?

Yes that is the most possible and Robust solution.  More over I would like to suggest, make it `static`

```
public static String USER_TYPE = rpc.getUserType();
```

That variable should initialize with a value in very first of `onModuleLoad` and should be in to whole application.

> But i think, that i have to make rpc call before each construction like if(userType=blah-blah-blah) add(something)

No that raises performance issues and unnecessary `server` calls through the wire.

> because I think that GWT translates my Java code to Javascript which runs on client side and all variables can be modified with programms like ArtMoney.

GWT secure enough and compile your module with the option **Obfuscated**, which makes your code not human readable in browser.

That Obfuscation alone protect from all vulnerable things, there are some other steps also needs to be taken to sleep happy :)

I'm suggesting to go through the GWT [security documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/security_for_gwt_applications.html).

**Besides all,**

While saving or processing data on serverside that check you done on client side needs to be done strictly, So that you cn avoid such situation.

On server side

```
if(clientsideUserType.equals(serverSideUserType))  // 
{
 // Then only insert/process data
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for sharing your point, I will try to rely on obfuscation. If some cool hacker will be able to de-obfuscate java script I can simply add rpc call before each "render-on-condition" construction)

Comment: @Baurzhan Updated my post. Don't get hacker to do some cool stuff with your app :)